# C++: Print only one char

Tags: c++, pointers, char, iostream

When I read one `char*` from `std::cin` and I want to write it to `std::cout`, it prints until it finds a `\0` in memory. So what did was:

```
char c;
cin >> c;
char* pChar = &c;
pChar++;
*pChar = '\0';
println(&c); // My own method: void println(char * str) { cout << str << endl; }
```

But I don't think this is a safe action.

Is there a safer way to do this?

Comment: I'd like to find out what you are trying to achieve before answering. Your code looks much too complicated if you are just trying to copy from cin to cout.

Comment: Your code is Undefined Behavior. You are creating a variable in the stack, then creating a pointer to it and finally overwritting an address beyond the reserved space. Your code is not only unsafe, it is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply:

```
char c;
cin >> c;
cout << c;
```

Comment: Does not do what the OP asked.

Comment: So the problem is that I pass it as a `char*` which cout << ... handles as a char sequence. And if I make a method println(char c) it would work?

Comment: @Martijn: It checks whether inputting succeeded. There isn't much that could go wrong when reading a character, but any input operation will also fail if previous input operations failed and the input stream still in a bad state. Didier's code will then print a random character.

Comment: @Neil: Little question: What does OP mean?

Comment: @Matijn: "Original Posting" or "Original Poster" - a term that, I think, comes from Usenet.

Comment: @sbi,@Didier: with "char c = 0;" all is ok. It's a POD, need to be initialized.

Comment: @Neil: Why do you think this is not what the OP is asking for?

Comment: @Martin He was asking about calling his own println() function. I seem to be the only person who actually answered that. Sigh.

Comment: @Neil: I'm not really sure what the question was, but the title is: "C++: Print only one char". It seems he made his own function because he had a problem.

Comment: @Neil: Martijn wrote "I read one char* from std::cin and I want to write it to std::cout", and only in his code there was a `println()` function, which I (and, apparently, others) took as artifacts of his struggle to get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

The right thing to do when you want to print a character, of course, is to print that character:

```
char ch;
if(std::cin >>ch) 
  std::cout << ch;
else
  // handle input error
```

And if you, for whatever reason, want a newline behind every character, then do just that:

```
std::cout << char << '\n';
```

Note: You will also see `std::endl` used for outputting a newline, but `std::endl` does two things: it outputs a `'\n'` and *flushes the output buffer*. While the latter isn't a problem when outputting to the console (it's still faster than a human will be able to read it), I have seen applications becoming to slow (on file output) due to the use of `std::endl` instead of `'\n'`. So you'd better learn from the beginning to pay attention whether you need those buffers flushed or not.

---

Note that, where you're doing

```
pChar++;
*pChar = '\0';
```

you're invoking the dreaded *Undefined Behavior*: With `pChar++` you are incrementing the pointer to point behind your variable (which is fine), and with `*pChar = ...` you are writing to whatever memory happens to be behind your variable.
In practice, this will likely corrupt your stack, hopefully making your application crash in the very next moment. In theory, however, this invokes undefined behavior, which, according to the C++ standard, might do anything (including the often cited possibility that it might format your disk).
***Do not write to memory that you don't own.***
It *is* hard for beginners to get pointers right, so just avoid them wherever you can. You can do a lot with C++ without ever manually fiddling with pointers.

Comment: POD should be initialized anyway :P

Comment: @Nikko: No, why? It's value will be overridden in the very next statement (if the input succeeds). What good would it be to set it to some value before that?

Comment: its value won't be if std::cin fail :)

Comment: @Nikko: That's why it's value isn't accessed (in this case: printed) if input fails.

Answer (score 2):

***There already are some answers on how to do what you want to do, but I would like to explain what actually beneath those `pchar++` in your code and why it's evil.***

*C-style* casting grants flexibility, but allows you to shoot yourself in the foot. You've allocated `char c` on the stack (that means you have exact amount of memory reserved for it, and it equals `sizeof(char)`, which is exactlye `1` byte).

Then you take a memory address of your variable (that's ok), so you have your `char` variable and a ***pointer*** to the memory where this `char` is located. But your next step is completely evil, *because you (when doing `*(pchar + 1) = 0`) are actually corrupting the stack.*

As I've told earlier the compiler reserved exactly one byte for your char memory, but what you do means explicitly traversing to the next byte in that memory *(which could even belong to other program's stack)* and rewriting it with your own values.

***This behaviour could be also described with the following example:***

*Think that you have to alter the contents of some concrete file (`a.file`) on your hard disk. Do you think it's ok to rewrite the contents of files that sequentially follow `a.file`, for example, increase the size of that `a.file`?*

Comment: In theory, at least from what I know, most modern OSes will prevent a process from writing to memory it doesn't own (unless of course it is explicitly shared member). While I do agree with the fact it will corrupt the stack, BUT in most modern OSes it won't because the OS will block the process.

Comment: Thanks, it is what I thought. Does this cause a memory leak.

Comment: Try understanding what does a *memory leak* mean. I know, this could be hard when porting yourself from Java to C or C++, but you should know what does it stand for.

Comment: @Nathan Probably, yes, but I don't think it should excuse people who are doing evil things like that.

Comment: @Nathan: It is so __very__ likely that the process owns the memory behind a stack variable, it is almost certain.

Comment: @Kotti Completely agree, just want to paint the bigger picture. And I mean "memory" not "member". I haven't had my coffee yet :P.

Answer (score 1):

```
char c;
cin >> c;
char pChar[2] = {0};
pChar[0] = c;;
println(pChar);
```

Or if you want to be more C++ like, overload the functions:

```
void println( const char * s ) {
   cout << s << endl;
}

void println( char  c ) {
   cout << c << endl;
}
```

Or  even  template:

```
template <typename T >
void println( T t ) {
   cout << t << endl;
}
```

Comment: You can't pass a `char[]` to `char*`.

Comment: @Martijn: What makes you say that?

Answer (score 0):

Print the character you entered:

```
char c = 0;
std::cin >> c;
std::cout << c;
```

Get the character in a string and get the first character:

```
char c = 0;
std::cin >> c;
std::string str;
str += c;

std::cout << str.at(0) << std::endl;
```

**EDIT**

Or maybe you asked for this? :

```
std::string str;
std::cin >> str;

std::cout << str;
```

I'm not really sure what is really the problem.

Comment: `<sigh>` And if input fails, your code prints a random character. (That annoys your fellow-workers to no ends of it happens to be a `0x7`.)

Comment: Ok I forgot to initialize the char :) If std::cin fail it does not change the input.

Comment: And now, if input fails, it silently prints nothing at all. I'm sorry to say, but I don't really see this as an improvement.

Comment: Because it's just a simple example? And it's not really the point to see why it is needed if I don't initialize the char and why I don't need it for a std::string that has a constructor... the OP being I think a beginner..

Answer (score 0):

```
char c;
std::cin >> c;
if (std::cin) {
    std::cout << c << std::flush;
}
```

That code prints "only one char". `std::cout << c << std::endl` prints two: `c` and `'\n'`.

You can also use your `println` function if you wanted:

```
char str[2] = {'\0', '\0'};
std::cin >> str[0];
if (std::cin) {
    println(str);
}
```

Note that `if (std::cin)` causes the compiler to invoke the [`operator void*() const`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/operator_voidpt/) member of the `std::ios` class, which `std::istream` extends, in order to evaluate `std::cin` as a boolean.